# How to deselect all content in a Monaco editor

Tags: javascript, selection, monaco-editor, textselection

I have a monaco editor in my UI, and I'd like to programmatically unselect all selected ranges within it.

`editor.getSelection()` can apparently return null, according to its type definitions, but I've tried `editor.setSelection(null)` and `editor.setSelections([])`, and both fail complaining that the argument is invalid.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Passing a new empty selection worked for me.

```js
editor.setSelection(new monaco.Selection(0, 0, 0, 0));
```